# How do I launch the Maps application as full-screen in Android Automotive 12 and later?

Tags: android-automotive

In Android 11, the map application could be shown as a portion of the home screen or in full screen mode (with nothing but the top and bottom system bars so the maps app got most of the screen real estate).

Specifically, under `frameworks/base/packages/CarSystemUI/res/layout/car_navigation_bar.xml`, here is the portion with the icon for the Maps application:

```xml
        <com.android.systemui.car.navigationbar.CarNavigationButton
            android:id="@+id/maps_nav"
            style="@style/NavigationBarButton"
            systemui:categories="android.intent.category.APP_MAPS"
            systemui:icon="@drawable/car_ic_navigation"
            systemui:intent="intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.APP_MAPS;launchFlags=0x14000000;end"
            systemui:selectedIcon="@drawable/car_ic_navigation_selected"
            systemui:highlightWhenSelected="true"
        />
```

Tapping this icon took the maps app full screen.

In newer versions of Android, the map icon has been removed. Putting it back in does not achieve the expected result of taking the maps app into full screen mode. It just goes home, the same as tapping the home icon. In fact, now, even tapping the maps icon from the app launcher grid just goes back home.

In Android 12, 12.1, or 13, when I tried to put it back in, (while updating the class name & style to match the other buttons) I added this to `packages/apps/Car/SystemUI/res/layout/car_bottom_system_bar.xml`:

```xml
            <com.android.systemui.car.systembar.CarSystemBarButton
                android:id="@+id/maps_nav"
                style="@style/SystemBarButton"
                systemui:categories="android.intent.category.APP_MAPS"
                systemui:icon="@drawable/car_ic_navigation"
                systemui:intent="intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.APP_MAPS;launchFlags=0x14000000;end"
                systemui:selectedIcon="@drawable/car_ic_navigation_selected"
                systemui:highlightWhenSelected="true"/>
```

I also tried this intent to more closely match the other icons.

```xml
            <com.android.systemui.car.systembar.CarSystemBarButton
                android:id="@+id/maps_nav"
                style="@style/SystemBarButton"
                systemui:categories="android.intent.category.APP_MAPS"
                systemui:icon="@drawable/car_ic_navigation"
                systemui:intent="intent:#Intent;component=com.android.car.carlauncher/.CarLauncher;category=android.intent.category.APP_MAPS;launchFlags=0x24000000;end"
                systemui:selectedIcon="@drawable/car_ic_navigation_selected"
                systemui:highlightWhenSelected="true"/>
```

How can I get it back to the old way, where tapping the maps icon in the bottom system bar or in the app launcher grid goes full screen?

This was tested in as "vanilla" a build as I could get with Android Automotive, using tag android-13.0.0_r75